# Google+ Sign in Android Keytool

Tags: android, google-plus, sha

I am trying to learn Android development and I am having trouble following the Google+ sign in tutorial.https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/android . I am stuck on step 6e-getting the SHA-1 fingerprint with the keytool.

I don't quite understand what this process is doing. In the command prompt, I have navigated to the Java/bin folder, and when I put in the command:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore <C:/Users/Me/.android/debug.keystore> -list -v
```

it says access denied.

Answer (score 1):

This command should work:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore -list -v
```

Comment: i am  also stuck in Google Sign In, can you please help me too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30908346/android-google-sign-in-googleapiclient-connect